# Slow query, state = 'Sorting result' mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have generated query

```
select 
    mailsource2_.file as col_0_0_, 
    messagedet0_.messageId as col_1_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffset as col_2_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffsetEnd as col_3_0_, 
    messagedet0_.id as col_4_0_ 
from MessageDetails messagedet0_, MessageEntry messageent1_, MailSourceFile mailsource2_ 
where messagedet0_.id=messageent1_.messageDetails_id 
and messageent1_.mailSourceFile_id=mailsource2_.id 
order by mailsource2_.file, messageent1_.mboxOffset;
```

Explain says that there is no full scans and indexes are used:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                                        |key     | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mailsource2_ | index  | PRIMARY                                              |file    | 384     | NULL                                 | 1445 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messageent1_ | ref    | msf_idx,md_idx,FKBBB258CB60B94D38,FKBBB258CBF7C835B8 |msf_idx | 9       | skryb.mailsource2_.id                | 2721 | Using where           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messagedet0_ | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                              |PRIMARY | 8       | skryb.messageent1_.messageDetails_id |    1 |           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+


CREATE TABLE `mailsourcefile` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(127) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `file` (`file`),
  KEY `File_idx` (`file`),
  KEY `Archive_idx` (`archive_id`),
  KEY `FK7C3F816ECDB9F63C` (`archive_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7C3F816ECDB9F63C` FOREIGN KEY (`archive_id`) REFERENCES `archive` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1370 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Also I have indexes for file and mboxOffset. SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST says that mysql is sorting result and it takes more then few minutes. Resultset size is 5M records. How can I optimize this?

Comment: instead of using cartisian product means FROM table1, table2 ... use joins they are much faster and will fetch only related data. Whearas FROM blah1 , blah2 will fetch undesired result

Comment: if you can put structure of your tables it will be easy to optimize

Comment: @stiv Can you also post the explain statement you are referring to?

Comment: yes i can, few mins please.

Comment: MySQL thinks its going to generate 1500 rows. You're generating 5M. Might be time for `analyze table`!

Comment: Also, what are your sort settings in `my.cnf`? Sorting 5M rows is going to take some time...

Comment: @derobert Actually, MySQL thinks it's going to generate 1445 * 2721 * 1 rows, which is just under 4M.

Comment: @stiv Can you post the table structures? I'm curious to see your file index in mailsource2

Comment: Isn't it generally going to be troublesome sorting a large set of items that are so large (at least 384 bytes)? What if they are not evenly distributed? That could be a lot of comparison operations...

Comment: added table definition. my my.cnf sort settings are default

Comment: You say it takes more than a few minutes. What is an acceptable query time?

Comment: Well, in fact I can wait even this time. This quiery is not for user interaction but for a very long background job. Though I think it is possible to process this amount of data faster, that's why I asked.

Comment: Could you provide sample data? What's your MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION();` and is altering the table itself an option for optimization?

Comment: I'd like to see the structure of all tables you query from, at least messageEntry

Comment: This is probably obvious, but I believe the vast majority of the time is spent creating a temporary table with the 5 million or so records and sorting it. I'd suggest looking into whether removing the `ORDER BY` is at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think there is much optimization to do in the query itself. Joins would make it more readable, but iirc mysql nowadays is perfectly able to detect these kind of constructs and plan the joins itself.

What would help propably is to increase both the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size to allow the resultset of this query to remain in memory, rather than having to write it to disk.

> The maximum size for in-memory temporary tables is the minimum of the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size values

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

The "using temporary" in the explain denotes that it is using a temporary table (see the link above again) - which will probably be written to disk due to the large amount of data (again, see the link above for more on this).
the file column alone is anywhere between 1 and 384 bytes, so lets take the half for our estimation and ignore the rest of the columns, that leads to 192 bytes per row in the result-set.

```
1445 * 2721  =   3,931,845 rows
     * 192   = 754,914,240 bytes
     / 1024 ~=     737,221 kb
     / 1024 ~=         710 mb
```

This is certainly more than the max_heap_table_size (16,777,216 bytes) and most likely more than the tmp_table_size.

Not having to write such a result to disk will most certainly increase speed.

Good luck!

Comment: oh yes, writing to hdd takes lots of time, I'll try to tune it and give u bounty if it will speed it up

Answer (score 3):

Optimization is always tricky. In order to make a dent in your execution time, I think you probably need to do **some** sort of pre-cooking.

If the file names are similar, (e.g. /path/to/file/1, /path/to/file/2), sorting them will mean a lot of byte comparisons, probably compounded by the unicode encoding. I would calculate a hash of the filename on insertion (e.g. MD5()) and then sort using that.

If the files are already well distributed (e.g. postfix spool names), you probably need to come up with some scheme on insertion whereby either:

1. simply reading records from some joined table will automatically generate them in correct order; this may not save a lot of time, but it will give you some data quickly so you can start processing, or
2. find a way to provide a "window" on the data so that not all of it needs to be processed at once.

Answer (score 1):

As @raheel shan said above, you may want to try some `JOIN`s:

```
select 
    mailsource2_.file as col_0_0_, 
    messagedet0_.messageId as col_1_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffset as col_2_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffsetEnd as col_3_0_, 
    messagedet0_.id as col_4_0_ 
from 
  MessageDetails messagedet0_ 
inner join 
  MessageEntry messageent1_ 
on 
  messagedet0_.id = messageent1_.messageDetails_id 
inner join 
  MailSourceFile mailsource2_ 
on 
  messageent1_.mailSourceFile_id = mailsource2_.id
order by 
  mailsource2_.file, 
  messageent1_.mboxOffset
```

My apologies if the keys are off, but I think I've conveyed the point.

Comment: this doesn't change anything

Comment: Whether the join conditions are on the join themselves or in the where clause should not have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

write the query with joins like

**select**

mailsource2_.file as col_0_0_, 
    messagedet0_.messageId as col_1_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffset as col_2_0_, 
    messageent1_.mboxOffsetEnd as col_3_0_, 
    messagedet0_.id as col_4_0_

**from** 
  MessageDetails m0

**inner join** 
  MessageEntry m1 
**on** 
  m0.id = m1.messageDetails_id

**inner join** 
  MailSourceFile m2 
**on** 
  m1.mailSourceFile_id = m2.id

**order by** 
  m2_.file, 
  m1_.mboxOffset;

on seeing ur explain i found 3 things which in my opinion are not good

1 file sort in extra column

2 index in type column

3 key length which is 384

if you reduce the key length you may get quick retrieval for that consider the character set you use and the partial indexes

here you can do force index for order by and use index for join ( create appropriate multi column indexes and assign them) remember it is alway good to order with column present in the same table

index type represents it is scanning entire index column which is not good

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I don't understand what's 'index in type column'? What is its name in my situation?

Comment: type column in the explain result set should not contain index which indicates it is scanning entire index......your query improvement based on extra column and type column present in the explain result set